# Looking for C source code for snprintf()

Tags: glibc, printf, newlib

I need to port snprintf() to another platform that does not fully support GLibC.

I am looking for the underlying declaration in the Glibc 2.14 source code.  I follow many function calls, but get stuck on vfprintf().  It then seems to call _IO_vfprintf(), but I cannot find the definition.  Probably a macro is obfuscating things.

I need to see the real C code that scans the format string and calculates the number of bytes it would write if input buffer was large enough.

I also tried looking in newlib 1.19.0, but I got stuck on _svfprintf_r().  I cannot find the definition anywhere.

Can someone point me to either definition or another one for snprintf()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.ijs.si/software/snprintf/ has what they claim is *a portable implementation of snprintf, including vsnprintf.c, asnprintf, vasnprintf, asprintf, vasprintf*. Perhaps it can help.

Comment: However good it seems, this implementation does NOT support any float/double formatting, so it is far from complete.

Answer (score 6):

I've spent quite a while digging the sources to find `_svfprintf_r()` (and friends) definitions in the Newlib. Since OP asked about it, I'll post my finding for the poor souls who need those as well. The following holds true for Newlib 1.20.0, but I guess it is more or less the same across different versions.

The actual sources are located in the *vfprintf.c* file. There is a macro `_VFPRINTF_R` set to one of `_svfiprintf_r`, `_vfiprintf_r`, `_svfprintf_r`, or `_vfprintf_r` (depending on the build options), and then the actual implementation function is defined accordingly:

```c
int
_DEFUN(_VFPRINTF_R, (data, fp, fmt0, ap),
       struct _reent *data _AND
       FILE * fp           _AND
       _CONST char *fmt0   _AND
       va_list ap)
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

The source code of the GNU C library (glibc) is hosted on [sourceware.org](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git).

Here is a link to the implementation of `vfprintf()`, which is called by `snprintf()`:
https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c

Comment: I checked the URL you provided.  I see: `#ifndef COMPILE_WPRINTF ... # define vfprintf       _IO_vfprintf_internal`, but where is `_IO_vfprintf_internal` defined?  Let me know if I misunderstand.

Comment: The definition of `vfprintf()` starts at [line 1235](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c#l1235).

Comment: `vfprintf()` now starts at [line 1244](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c#l1244).

Comment: It `JUMP`s a lot!